# Unit test using Rhino Mock

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

```
[Test]
public void OnActionExecuting_Always_Call_CheckStatisticActionAuthorization()
{
    //Arrange
    var _ActionExecutingContext = GetActionExecutingContext();
    var _StatisticController = MockRepository.GenerateStub<StatisticsController>();

    _StatisticController.DataContext = fDataContext;

    //Act
    _StatisticController.OnActionExecuting(_ActionExecutingContext, false);

    //Assert
    _StatisticController.AssertWasCalled(aStatisticController =>
          aStatisticController.CheckStatisticActionAuthorization(_ActionExecutingContext));
}
```

I keep getting NullReferenceException from CheckStatisticActionAuthorization the StatisticController.DataContext is null. What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Where does `fDataContext` come from? You're not creating it anywhere in the sample you provided.

Comment: What are the relevant implementation details of `StatisticsController`?

Answer (score 0):

Try out specifying `PropertyBehavior()` for the DataContext property:

```
var statisticController = MockRepository.GenerateStub<StatisticsController>(); 
statisticController.Expect(m => m.DataContext).PropertyBehavior();
statisticController.DataContext = fDataContext;

// check whether it set properly
Assert.AreEqual(fDataContext, statisticController.DataContext);
Assert.IsNotNull(statisticController.DataContext);

// Act
// ...

// Assert
// ..
```

See [Rhino Mocks Properties](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Properties.ashx) for more details